# iPhone Cookie Persistence

Tags: iphone, cookies

In my iPhone app, every time I relaunch my cookies are cleared. This is using the NSURLRequesst and NSHTTPCookieStorage. And no, they are not session only cookies.

How can I get NSHTTPCookieStorage to keep my cookies around, and if I can't, what is the proper way to store them (preference, keychain, etc.).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Edit**

http://log.scifihifi.com/post/55837387/simple-iphone-keychain-code

Comment: I am storing login credentials. Hence my hesitance to use the user defaults. I read somewhere about storing cookies in the keychain, but I can't seem to find it.

Comment: Ah I see, yes this would need to be stored in the Keychain, i updated my answer.

Comment: Please don't provide link-only answers -- if the link disappears, so does all the information you wanted to share with the community. Please post relevant information, or at least relevant excerpts, directly in your answer.